# How to add Text Composable in onResponse ? Jetapck Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My English is weak so please manage

I'm trying to get data from json after decoding json How can i add the decoded data to a Text Composable

Here is my Code

```
@Composable
fun Api(){
    val url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val body = response.body()?.string()
            val gson = Gson()
            val bundle = gson.fromJson(body, Array<Json>::class.java)
            for(element in bundle){
                val title = element.title
                TODO("How to add title value to Text Composable")
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            print("Error")
        }
    })
}
```

Here is my Data class

```
data class Json(
    @field:SerializedName("title")
    val title: String? = null,
)
```

Comment: Where is the Text composable?

Comment: You can see TODO i want to add there but it gives error

Comment: You need to reconsider your approach and not load data in your composables. Your composables should receive an immutble state and render the UI based on that state - nothing else. Your data should be loaded in a viewmodel and then transformed into a state.

Answer (score 1):

You should move your logic in a ViewModel, loading the data and expose the value to the Text as a state.

If you want to use your example you can define your `Text`:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
Text (text = text)
```

Then just update the text value:

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
             //...

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                response.use {
                    //....
                    text = //your logic
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: This will not work because the onResponse method is asynchronous and is not Composable.
This requires a complete refactor of the original code by using a viewmodel to fetch the data and then expose it to the composable as a state, loading the data in a composable is the wrong solution.

Comment: @Francesc No. It is not the best solution, I agree, you should use a viemodel. But it is just an example and it works.